# switch to change LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'd like to change the LINQ query based on what `productID` we pass into this method and then to add the where and selects to it after the correct query was selected

the second select is telling me an explicit conversion exists

I have 3 questions

1) why does it care what the first evaluation would set `planInfo` to? I'm thinking if I ran this code it would never set `planInfo` to `LTDRatesSelected` if the `productID` didn't match and the second case shouldn't need it to be converted (I hope I make sense) since the first case statement was never executed.

2) what can I do to make this work or  are there other ways of accomplishing the same thing?

3) what can I do to initialize `planInfo` outside the scope of the switch? I'd like it to be anonymous

```
switch (ProductId)
{
      case (int)Products.LTD:
         var planInfo = from i in context.LTDRatesSelecteds
                        select i;
         break;
      case (int)Products.LADD:
         planInfo = from i in context.LADDRatesSelecteds
                    select i;
         break;
      case (int)Products.STD:
         planInfo = from i in context.STDRatesSelecteds
                    select i;
         break;
      case (int)Products.VoluntaryLife:
         planInfo = from i in context.VoluntaryLifeRatesSelecteds
                    select i;
         break;
      case (int)Products.Dental:
         planInfo = from i in context.DentalRatesSelecteds
                    select i;
         break;
      case (int)Products.Vision:
         planInfo = from i in context.VisionRatesSelecteds
                    select i;
         break;

}
//planInfo.Where(i=> i.PlanCode == "somevalue" && i.Something else == "someothervalue").Select();
```

Comment: `var planInfo` will never be called for the other cases, so it's never defined at all. You're working with an undefined variable at those points.

Comment: Which columns do you want from the tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring the planInfo variable in an inner scope that is not accessible after that case statement.

To see it clearly, substitute your switch for a bunch of if..else blocks and you will see it:

```
if (ProductId == (int)Products.LTD)
{
    var planInfo = from i in context.LTDRatesSelecteds
                           select i;
}
else if (ProductId == (int)Products.LADD)
{
    planInfo = from i in context.LADDRatesSelecteds
                           select i;
}
```

The switch is equivalent to the code above and you will clearly see that on the second block (the else block) planInfo does not exist, it is out of that scope.

If you want to use planInfo after the switch it must be declared before that switch. But then you can't make it an anonymous type because anonymous types have to be assigned straight away.

What you can do is to declare planInfo as IEnumerable (from System.Collections) before the switch, but you will have to cast it to do the where after the switch:

```
IEnumerable planInfo;

switch (ProductId)
{
     case (int)Products.LTD:
          planInfo = from i in context.LTDRatesSelecteds
                     select i;
          break;
     case (int)Products.LADD:
          planInfo = from i in context.LADDRatesSelecteds
                     select i;
          break;

     [..]
}
```

If you detail a little more what you would like to accomplish perhaps I could help more. Possibly the ideal here would be that all your types of rates should inherit from a common type that contains their common properties but I can't detail how to do that without further information.

Comment: it won't let me query planInfo any further. For example after one of those switches is met I take planInfo and try to do something like planInfo = planInfo.Where(i=>i.something == somethingelse).Select(i=>i); and it complains that IEnumerable doesn't have .Where(). I have a reference to LINQ. Any ideas?

Comment: I might be mistaken but I think in order to be able to perform queries with linq your object needs to be of IEnumerable<T>, so IEnumerable would not suffice

Comment: Seems to be true. I"ve adjusted the code to cast each query but it still will not let me use .Where on it

Answer (score 1):

As I'm sure you're aware, using `var planInfo = [assignment]` your planInfo receives its type from the right side of equals.

It looks like in each switch statement "planInfo" represents a different object type.  In your first switch your planInfo is being assigned to of type (let's say) `IEnumerable<LTDRatesSelecteds>`

your second is of `IEnumerable<LADDRatesSelecteds>` - these two types are not interchangeable and it looks like your planInfo in everything but the first statement never gets initialized.

what are you doing with planInfo after initial assignment?  Does the same behavior occur on each "version" of plan info?  If that's the case, you could likely throw your methods into an interface and assign to that rather than "var".

Comment: Yes, I will basically be doing the same thing with each version of planInfo

Comment: += which is performing additional queries

Answer (score 1):

one way is to declare the variable every time in the cases, if you need it to be an external scope you could use the dynamic keyword for the objects.  You will need to be very careful however with what you do with the planInfo object after that since there is no guarantee, and infact it is a certainty that from one run to the next the object will not be the same data type

```
dynamic planInfo;
switch (ProductId)
    {
        case (int)Products.LTD:
            planInfo = from i in context.LTDRatesSelecteds
                           select i;
            break;
        case (int)Products.LADD:
            planInfo = from i in context.LADDRatesSelecteds
                       select i;
            break;
        case (int)Products.STD:
            planInfo = from i in context.STDRatesSelecteds
                       select i;
            break;
        case (int)Products.VoluntaryLife:
            planInfo = from i in context.VoluntaryLifeRatesSelecteds
                       select i;
            break;
        case (int)Products.Dental:
            planInfo = from i in context.DentalRatesSelecteds
                       select i;
            break;
        case (int)Products.Vision:
            planInfo = from i in context.VisionRatesSelecteds
                       select i;
            break;

    }
```

Comment: This will work, but if you've never worked with dynamic before, I would suggest reading up a bit on it before diving in as there are quite a few disadvantages to go along with the advantages it provides.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx